# VBA to copy a row from master sheet then add to bottom of data in each extracted sheets

Tags: vba, excel, loops

from my master sheet (JV501) at the bottom most is a row which I need to copy in every sheet I've extracted so far. It needs to be copied also in every bottom of data.

```
futureuse          |          Price        |        Credit             |     Currency   | 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
300x               |          6151500      |                           |          EUR   |
300x               |          6151500      |                           |          USD   |
300x               |          6151500      |        8896684.6          |
```

above is a sample data, the third row with the Credit needs to be copied in every data I've extracted, I've extracted sheets based on 'Currency Column'

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub SortCurrency()

    Dim currRange As Range, dataRng As Range, currCell As Range
    Call DeleteSheets
    Dim lastcol As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim lastrow2 As Long
    Dim Idx As Variant

    With Worksheets("JV501")
    .Select
        Set currRange = .Range("AB1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp))
        Set dataRng = Intersect(.UsedRange, currRange.EntireRow)
        lastcol = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
        lastrow = Range("AB2").End(xlDown).Row
        Range("AB2:AB" & lastrow).sort key1:=Range("AB2" & lastrow), _
        order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

        With .UsedRange
            .Resize(1, 1).Offset(0, lastcol - 1).Select
             With .Resize(1, 1).Offset(0, lastcol)
                With .Resize(currRange.Rows.Count)
                .Value = currRange.Value
                .RemoveDuplicates Array(1), Header:=xlYes
                Range("AB:AB").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Checklist").Range("A1")
                For Each currCell In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                    currRange.AutoFilter , field:=1, Criteria1:=currCell.Value

                    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, currRange) - 1 > 0 Then
                        dataRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=GetOrCreateWorksheet(currCell.Value).Range("A1")
                        Range("A:A").EntireColumn.Delete
                        Range("J:Q").EntireColumn.Delete
                        Columns("A:V").Select
                        Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit
                    End If

                 Next currCell
                 .ClearContents

                End With
             End With
         End With
         .AutoFilterMode = False

    End With
    End Sub
    Function GetOrCreateWorksheet(shtName As String) As Worksheet
        On Error Resume Next

        Set GetOrCreateWorksheet = Worksheets(shtName)
        If GetOrCreateWorksheet Is Nothing Then
            Set GetOrCreateWorksheet = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
            GetOrCreateWorksheet.Name = shtName
        End If

    End Function
    Sub DeleteSheets()
       Dim ws As Worksheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "JV501" And ws.Name <> "details" And ws.Name <> "removed" And ws.Name <> "Checklist" Then ws.Delete
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    End Sub
    Sub countCurrency()

     Dim sffCount As Long
     Dim ws As Worksheet
     Set ws = Sheets("Checklist")
     Dim lastrow As Long
     lastrow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     Dim Idx As Variant

     For Idx = 2 To lastrow

     sffCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("A1:A" & ws.Rows.Count), ws.Cells(Idx, "A").Value)

     ws.Cells(Idx, "B") = sffCount


 Next

 End Sub
```

I'm sorry if it's quite long since I'm also try to get the count of my currency (Under Sub countCurrency) and copy to another sheet called "Checklist" which is also my problem I need to sort and filter also

Every help is very much appreciated!!!

Comment: Where exactly is the problem. If you are trying to copy to the last row (in R it would be an rbind), then you would have something like - SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1000000").end(xlup).offset(1,0)

Comment: Hi @Lowpar I'm sorry for the late reply, I need to copy the last row in my masterfile which is the (JV501) then copy those to my 'GetOrCreateWorksheet' lastrow which I extracted from my master file.

Comment: got this working by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it working

```
With Worksheets("JV501")

 Dim copyS As Range, copyR As Range,
    Set copyR = Range("R" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp) 'find lastrow of column R
    Set copyS = Range("S" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
```

then under my if loop

```
internalR = Range("R" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            copyR.copy Destination:=Range("R" & internalR)

                            internalS = Range("S" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            copyS.copy Destination:=Range("S" & internalS)
```

this will add in the lastrow +1 of my debit column